# boost Date_Time date parsing doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to write code to parse date time string using boost 1.55 Date_Time library. But it always produces not-a-date-time date.

```
boost::gregorian::date d(2005, 6, 25);
boost::gregorian::date d2;
boost::gregorian::date_facet* facet(new boost::gregorian::date_facet("%Y %m %d"));
stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));

ss << d; string s = ss.str(); // s = "2005 06 25"
cout << s << endl;
    stringstream ss2(s);
ss2 >> d2; // not-a-date-time
cout << d2 << endl;
```

I tried different format specifiers, but it didn't help.
I'm using Visual C++ 2013.
Is there something wrong with my code?

UPDATE:

My system locale is Russian if that makes any difference.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Mac OS

Comment: Seems like... um... You're reading off the end of empty after writing to a stream?  Wouldn't ss need to be seeked 0 or reset or something?

Comment: @ebyrob That too, see my edited answer. However, the fact was missing too

Comment: @ebyrob That's true. I oversimplified the sample code. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *parse* so you need the input facet:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c5a6c8aec89e4ec)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::gregorian::date const d(2005, 6, 25);
    boost::gregorian::date d2;

    std::stringstream oss;
    oss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::gregorian::date_facet("%Y %m %d")));

    oss << d; 

    oss.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet("%Y %m %d")));

    if (oss >> d2)
        std::cout << d2 << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Not parsed\n";
}
```

Prints

```
2005-Jun-25
```

on my machine