# Convert a date std::string into a QuantLib::Date object

Tags: c++, date, quantlib

As it often happens to read such strings from .csv or .txt files, I would like to know the simplest way to get a `%d/%m%/%y` (or any other similar format) string and convert it to something suitable to `QuantLib::Date` object [**constructor**](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_date.html).

Here below an example code:

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main() {

  boost::timer timer;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::string datesString = {
    ",17/10/2014,21/11/2014,19/12/2014,20/03/2015,19/06/2015,18/09/2015,18/12/2015,17/06/2016,"
  };
  std::vector<std::string> expiryDates;
  boost::split(expiryDates, datesString, boost::is_any_of(","));
  for(int i = 0; i < expiryDates.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << expiryDates[i] << std::endl;
  }
  // 17/10/2014
  // 21/11/2014
  // 19/12/2014
  // 20/03/2015
  // 19/06/2015
  // 18/09/2015
  // 18/12/2015
  // 17/06/2016

  // QuantLib::Date myQLDate(?);

  return 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kind of hidden, but once you include `<ql/utilities/dataparsers.hpp>` you can use:

```
Date d = DateParser::parseFormatted(expiryDates[i], format);
```

where `format` is a Boost.Date format string. In your case,

```
Date d = DateParser::parseFormatted(expiryDates[i], "%d/%m/%Y");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That *is* hidden.  +1 for you, -1 for the QuantLib documentation.

Comment: True. Until one or two years ago, this feature was quite restricted (it could only parse a few specific formats, like ISO) so it was kind of hidden on purpose... Now that it's fully generic, it might be worth moving to the `Date` class (either as a constructor taking the two strings, or as an `operator<<` for input streams). This would make it much more discoverable.

Answer (score 3):

```
  for(int i = 0; i < expiryDates.size(); i++)
  {
    int day, month, year;
    sscanf(expiryDates[i].c_str(), "%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year);
    QuantLib::Date myQLDate(day, month, year);
  }
```

Comment: This looks like a good way, but my compiler denounces no matching constructor for inizialization of `QuantLib::Date`.

Comment: Nice, but I would suggest parsing the date via the Boost Date classes, and then access day/month/year from them.  Just one more layer of 'making sure it is a valid date'. With QuantLib you always have Boost around anyway.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, replacing `QuantLib::Date myQLDate(day, month, year);` by `boost::gregorian::date d(day, month, year);` (of course with proper `#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"`) matches constructor but returns `Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000`.

Comment: Have you considered printing the value of the year?

Comment: I have, and I think the issue is that Gregorian requires this constructor: [**Construction**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_construction). Hence I should either change month's number into its 3-chars name or use [**Construct from string**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_construct_from_string) which conversely requires a different order of coordinates... any simpler way?

Comment: Please hone your Googling skills. Search for 'boost date from string' is not rocket science and leads to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class  Note the 'from string' constructors.

Comment: That's the same link I have added above, in my previous message, using hyperlinks to Gregorian documentation: `date from_string(std::string)` constructor asks for delimited date strings where with order year-month-day, e.g.: "2002/1/25", but on the contrary I have day-month-year and I don't figure out how to sort it out. Sorry for not being honed enough.

Comment: My bad, at work and have limited time.  I would start with a simple standalone Boost example and see if you can parse the date. Methinks you can, maybe I am wrong.  The older Boost *definitely* showed different date formats.

Comment: Have a look at this for a start:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412884/boost-date-time-date-parsing-doesnt-work  -- guess 'facet' will be your new best friend.  More here:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html